# Source code of arch command for macOS Catalina Version 10.15.3 (19D76)

Tags: source, macos, source-code

I need to get the source code of the "arch" command located in /usr/bin/arch for
macOS Catalina( see the output of sw_vers command below).

**macOS Catalina**

```bsh
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.3
BuildVersion:   19D76
```

In case you need it,  here are some architecture details:

```
MacBook-Pro 15-inch, 2019
Processor 2.3GHz * core Intel core i9
```

I found that macOS Catalina is one of many releases of Apple OS Darwin as explained here [Darwin OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)).

The same link also states that :

> Darwin is an open-source Unix-like operating system first released by
>   Apple Inc. in 2000. It is composed of code developed by Apple, as well
>   as code derived from NeXTSTEP, BSD, Mach, and other free software
>   projects.

So I thought that maybe I could find it here [Free BSD Source at GitHub](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd), but I had no luck there either.

Could someone please help?
Thanks!!

Comment: Try `https://opensource.apple.com/release/macos-1015.html`

Comment: It says at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system) that Catalina is the proprietary version. Darwin is the Free one. (It is a bit confusing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The place to find the open source components of MacOS is https://opensource.apple.com/ , and the package where `arch` is included is called `system_cmds`.

Unfortunately, the links for Catalina (10.15.x) seem to be unavailable at the time of writing this (this is not uncommon, because Apple usually publishes the source with some delay).

The version you want is probably `system_cmds-854.11.2` (the link is at https://opensource.apple.com/release/macos-1015.html but it is broken for the moment).

However, if you are fine with the version for Mojave (10.14.x), then you can get the source here: https://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-805.250.2/arch.tproj/

Hope this helps!

*Note: If you really need the Catalina version, you'll need to wait until Apple publishes it in the website above.*

Comment: Thank you for your help